# The importance of the phase in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-measurements

In introductory quantum mechanics I have always heard the mantra

> The phase of a wave function doesn't have physical meaning. So the states $| \psi \rangle$ and $\lambda|\psi \rangle$ with $|\lambda| = 1$ are physically  equivalent and indiscernible.

In fact by this motivation it is said that the state space of a physical system shouldn't be a Hilbert space, but rather a projective Hilbert space, where vectors which only differ up to a multiplicative constant of magnitude 1 are identified.

But I also heard that one of the defining "feature" of quantum mechanics is the superposition principle: We can  combine states  $| \psi_1 \rangle, |\psi_2 \rangle$ to a new state $| \psi_1 \rangle + | \psi_2 \rangle$. This should for example explain the constructive /  destructive interference we see in the double slit.

But if two states with the same phase are physically equivalent, so should the states $| \psi \rangle, -|\psi \rangle$. But their sum is zero. I have seen experiments which exploit this and measure the *relative* phase difference between two different states. But if relative phase difference is measurable, then surely the phase of a wave function does have physical  meaning? This should mean that we can identify the phases of all states of a quantum system up to a $U(1)$ transformation by gauging some state  to have phase $1$. Is this correct? How can this be solidified with the above mantra?

*I have asked a second question [here ("The superposition principle in quantum mechanics")](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552800/the-superposition-in-quantum-mechanics) regarding the superposition principle which is closely related to this question.*

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When people say that the phase doesn't matter, they mean the *overall*, "global" phase. In other words, the state $|0 \rangle$ is equivalent to $e^{i \theta} |0 \rangle$, the state $|1\rangle$ is equivalent to $e^{i \theta'} |1 \rangle$, and the state $|0\rangle + |1 \rangle$ is equivalent to $e^{i \theta''} (|0 \rangle + |1 \rangle)$.

Note that "equivalence" is not preserved under addition, since $e^{i \theta} |0 \rangle + e^{i \theta'} |1 \rangle$ is not equivalent to $|0 \rangle + |1 \rangle$, because there can be a relative phase $e^{i (\theta - \theta')}$. If we wanted to describe this very simple fact with unnecessarily big words, we could say something like "the complex projective Hilbert space of rays, the set of equivalence classes of nonzero vectors in the Hilbert space under multiplication by complex phase, cannot be endowed with the structure of a vector space".

Because the equivalence doesn't play nicely with addition, it's best to just ignore the global phase ambiguity whenever you're doing real calculations. Finally, when you're done with the entire calculation, and arrive at a state, you are free to multiply that final result by an overall phase.

Comment: So when we say "the phase doesn't matter" an analogous statement would be "mass doesn't matter" since we can always rescale our definition of mass by some constant. So the mass of an object isn't measurable, but its mass difference to another object is. The same way in QM: There is no notion of absolute phase since by a global $U(1)$-transformation we leave the physical content of  the theory intact.

Comment: @JannikPitt Sure, but I would quibble a little bit with this. The mass of an object (in the units we choose) is indeed arbitrary, since the units can be rescaled. But this is a trivial kind of redundancy that applies to literally any quantity in physics that isn't dimensionless. I would say the invariance under global phase redefinitions is qualitatively different, but yes, it gives the same kind of result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you say is the difference?

Comment: @JannikPitt I'm confused by your analogy. Why does the idea that you can express mass in different units mean that mass isn't measurable, but mass differences are? When you rescale your definition of mass by some constant, the mass differences also get rescaled by that same constant. I don't see how you can separate masses and mass differences in your analogy.

Comment: @probably_someone ... and in particular the phase is unit-less so comparison with the “rescaling” a mass is even more tenuous.

Comment: @JannikPitt for completeness: we don’t measure masses: we measure *ratios* of masses, and these ratios do not depend on any rescaling.

Comment: +1 "unnecessarily big words".  You made that very clear and easy to comprehend.  Would it be too big a favor for you to similarly answer pretty much every question on Physics and Math exchanges?

Comment: @wberry I appreciate the simple explanation, but I also like the relation to the "big words".. It helps to think of them in terms of simple examples.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to make @JannikPitt's analogy precise in a gauge-groupy way, but I don't know any gauge theory.  Skimming over [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/what-is-a-gauge/) post from Terry Tao makes me think that mass has an $\mathbb{R}_+$ symmetry (rescaling your reference mass) in the same way that state space has a $U(1)$ symmetry.  I'd like for someone more knowledgeable to comment, but if the main difference here is somehow just the choice of abelian gauge group, then Jannik's analogy seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I meant the ratio of the masses. But measurement in the real world always "yiealds a unitless quantity". It is only units that (we choose based on the method of our measurment, e.g. gauging a scale) give us the ability to compare our results to other results not obtained with the same method of measurement. Whether we measure the relative phase ratio (notice that here it is a ratio too) or the ratio of mass between a reference object and another object I think shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @JannikPitt We don't measure phase ratios. We measure phase differences. Phase differences are what are important for the physics of interference, after all.

Comment: I also believe the mass comparison is misguided. Mass is usually assumed to actually be a property of the object itself (even if we measure or model with comparisons). Relative phase (by definition) is a relational property between two or more parts of a quantum state. It is like the concept of "brother", "sister" or "ontop of", it applies to minimum two objects. There are weirdness's with defining any measure quantity (eg. mass), but relational quantities have another layer on top. If you ever have a single thing that has "brotherhood" without saying what too then you know you are wrong.

Answer (score 16):

The *global* phase does not matter.  In your example 
$\lambda(\vert\psi_1\rangle+\vert\psi_2\rangle)$ has the same physical contents as $\vert\psi_1\rangle+\vert\psi_2\rangle$ but this will be in general different from
$\vert\psi_1\rangle-\vert\psi_2\rangle$ or more generally $\lambda’(\vert\psi_1\rangle+e^{i\varphi}\vert\psi_1\rangle).$

... and of course yes the relative phase can be measured, as indicated for instance in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/353147/36194) and no doubt many others.  In fact interferometry depends on such relative phases.

Answer (score 9):

While the other answers are correct, this is not a different answer but rather an illustration that the *relative* phase is indeed important in quantum mechanics. We know that bosons (particles with integer spin) have the following property: a rotation by $2\pi$ (around any fixed axis) leaves their states invariant, $R(2\pi)|{\rm boson}\rangle = |{\rm boson}\rangle$. This is obviously fine, since a rotation by $2\pi$ should be a symmetry operation. Fermions (particles with integer-and-a-half spin) have the property that a rotation by $2\pi$ changes their sign: $R(2\pi)|{\rm fermion}\rangle = -|{\rm fermion}\rangle$. This is also fine, since 
$-|{\rm fermion}\rangle$ belongs to the same ray as $|{\rm fermion}\rangle$ and hence describes the same state.

What, however, if we want to make a linear superposition of the form $|\Psi\rangle = \alpha|{\rm boson}\rangle+\beta|{\rm fermion}\rangle$, with $\alpha\neq\beta$? It is clearly seen that the operation of rotation by $2\pi$ on $|\Psi\rangle$ will not give a state proportional to $|\Psi\rangle$, and so is not a symmetry of that state. What went wrong?

The answer is that we simply should not be making such superposition. While it is well-defined mathematically, it is *unphysical*: *it does not describe a state that can be physically prepared*. Thus, we are forbidden from making a (physical) superposition of a boson and a fermion. This is an example of a powerful class of statements known as **superselection rules**.

Comment: Very nice, something like this is exactly what I looked for.

Comment: +1: This is very interesting. How does this relate to the usual definition of superselection rules which goes something like "$\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are in different superselection sectors if $\langle \psi_1 | A | \psi_2\rangle=0$ for all observables $A$"?

Comment: -1: I don't think this is a correct explanation of superselection. Note that you could apply the same reasoning to almost any superposition: the momentum eigenstates $e^{ipx}$ and $e^{ikx}$ are "symmetric under translation" because translation just multiplies them by phases. Yet $e^{ipx} + e^{ikx}$ doesn't change by a phase. Does that mean that superpositions of different momenta are unphysical?

Comment: The point is that states that transform under different (i.e. non-equivalent) projective representations under a symmetry *that is believed to be an exact symmetry* belong to different superselection sectors. Bosons transform under ordinary single-valued representations. Fermions transform under double-valued *spinorial* representations. A linear combination "boson+fermion" does not have a well-defined transformation property under rotations.

Comment: @knzhou My understanding of superselection is very incipient so I might be completely wrong here, but, there appears to be a basic (relevant difference) between the superposition of momentum eigenstates and superposition of fermions+bosons: namely, a physical state needs to be invariant under rotations of $2\pi$ so a rotation of $2\pi$ can only add a phase to the overall state vector whereas a physical state doesn't need to be invariant under any non-trivial translations so the superposition of them is not creating any issue. Again, I might be completely wrongheaded about the whole thing.

Comment: @DvijD.C. The problem with this kind of argument is that you can just as easily use it to prove superselection rules that don't exist. Sure, let's say you don't think states "need" translational symmetry. Do they "need" parity? Isn't that just as obvious a symmetry as rotation by $2\pi$? But then you would conclude that a superposition of the $1s$ and $2p$ states in hydrogen is forbidden. (And parity violation is not relevant here, since QED conserves parity.)

Comment: @DvijD.C. Because of this, I think the only legitimate definition of superselection is the one you posted earlier. All of the other arguments can be tweaked to give any desired rules whatsoever, which makes them useless (though useful for causing endless confusion). For example, just above my comment OP says that you need "well-defined transformation property under rotations". That would _also_ exclude $1s$ and $2p$ superpositions, because $1s$ transforms trivially and $2p$ is in the $3d$ representation.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for your response. Shouldn't the analog of rotation by $2\pi$ be the squared parity operation? Whether or not parity is a symmetry of the theory is an empirical fact but the squared parity operator has to be identity apriori (just like the physical effect of rotation by $2\pi$ has to be represented by an identity transformation, apriori). However, I see, this line of reasoning has confused me even more :(

Comment: @DvijD.C. See, that's exactly why these arguments are confusing. There is absolutely no such thing as "a priori" in physics -- so whenever people claim to do "a priori" arguments, they're really doing nothing more than tweaking the argument until it gets the desired answer. How in the world is squared parity supposed to count but not parity? In that case, why not say that fermions prove that we need to consider $4 \pi$ rotations, not  $2 \pi$ rotations, in which case the fermion/boson superselection rule disappears?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Using such vague arguments, there is no doubt that you can arrive at an answer that matches the textbook answer. But if you didn't _already_ know what the textbook answer was supposed to be, you would have had no chance of getting it -- you would get some random other set of rules. (This is also the case for a lot of fancy mathematical formalizations of physical concepts: absolutely all the desired results are known ahead of time and put in by hand.)

Comment: @knzhou Just to clarify my comment about "a priori", obviously one cannot derive anything of non-trivial value by a priori arguments. However, one can often realize another aspect of some known physical truth by applying a priori considerations which simply amount to putting internal consistency requirements. Again, no new physics is supposed to come out of that, just our understanding might get clearer/explicit. The argument by OP just tempted me to think that maybe superselection rules can be seen as aspects of physically non-trivial symmetry principles.

Comment: @knzhou However, I do realize it looks hopeless in light of the counter examples you provided (and also, considering that superselection rules are not supposed to come out of the formalism of QM as such but from bare empirical reality about what observables we can measure). "In principle", there would be no superselection rules and thus, attempts at reaching them from formal arguments seems wrongheaded. Thanks for the educational comments! :)

Comment: You say the other answers are correct. All? It can change, so which?

Comment: Just to point out that this superselection rule is known as "univalence" superselection rule. There's a mention on p. 5 of Streater and Wightman [R. F. Streater and A. S. Wightman, *PCT, Spin And Statistics, And All That*, W. A. Benjamin, New York (1964)], where the operator is denoted as $(-1)^F$.

Answer (score 4):

> But I also heard that one of the defining "feature" of quantum
>   mechanics is the superposition principle: We can combine states
>   |ψ1⟩,|ψ2⟩ to a new state |ψ1⟩+|ψ2⟩
>
> ...
>
> But if two states with the same phase are physically equivalent, so
>   should the states |ψ⟩,−|ψ⟩.

This seems quite confused to me. $|\psi_n\rangle$ *isn't* a state, it's a state *vector*. Grokking this difference is, I believe, crucial to untangling your question.

That is, it is the state *vectors* that are superposed, not the states (which don't form a vector space).

UPDATE: to address this comment (since comments are ethereal)

> This should be a comment, nitpicking on terminology isn't an answer to
>   the question. The physical "object" we aim model is a state, and we do
>   that by assigning it a vector in some vector space. Then you could
>   call this object a state vector, but calling it a state without
>   differentiating between the object and the model works fine in most
>   context (doing theoretical calculations, about which this is all
>   about)

Weinberg is very careful in making the distinction between the state (ray) and the state-vectors in the ray when formulating Quantum Mechanics in section 2.1 of "The Quantum Theory of Fields". Here are some excerpts:

> (i) Physical states are represented by rays in Hilbert space.
>
> ...
>
> A *ray* is a set of normalized vectors (i.e., $(\Psi,\Psi)=1$) with
>   $\Psi$ and $\Psi'$ belonging to the same ray if $\Psi'=\xi\Psi$, where
>   $\xi$ is an arbitrary complex number with $|\xi|=1$.

...

> (iii) If a system is in a state represented by a ray $\mathscr{R}$,
>   and an experiment is done to test whether it is in any one of the
>   different states represented by mutually orthogonal rays
>   $\mathscr{R}_1,\,\mathscr{R}_2,\dots$, (for instance by measuring one
>   or more observables) then the probability of finding it in the state
>   represented by $\mathscr{R}_n$ is
>
> $$P(\mathscr{R}\rightarrow\mathscr{R}_n)=|(\Psi,\Psi_n)|^2$$
>
> where $\Psi$ and $\Psi_n$ are any vectors belonging to rays
>   $\mathscr{R}$ and $\mathscr{R}_n$ respectively. (A pair of rays is
>   said to be orthogonal if the state-vectors from the two rays have
>   vanishing scalar products).

In your question, you seem (to me) to be mixing the concepts of *state* and *state-vector* together and the resulting confusion is, I think, at the root of your question.

As I read the section I quoted from your question above, you seem to be saying that since $|\psi\rangle$ and $-|\psi\rangle$ are physically equivalent *states*, it *shouldn't* be that their sum is zero (and then go on to conclude that phase should be physical).

But that doesn't follow if you carefully distinguish between the state (ray) and vectors. We form linear combinations of vectors, not states.

Comment: This should be a comment, nitpicking on terminology isn't an  answer to the question. The physical "object" we aim model is a state, and we do that by assigning it a vector in some vector space. Then you could call this object a state vector, but calling it a state without differentiating between  the object and the model works fine in most context (doing theoretical calculations, about which this is all about).

Comment: @JannikPitt, I don't agree that it's nitpicking; your confusion seems to me to be conceptual in nature.  That's all I have to say about that.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean. How do you define the terms "state" and "state vector"?

Answer (score 3):

A fine example of physical behavior due to phase *change* is the [Aharonov-Bohm Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). A magnetic field that exerts no classical force on an electron nevertheless affects electron interference through the influence of the vector potential on the phase of the electron's wave function.

Answer (score 1):

Think of phase the same way you think of units.  The universe doesn't care if we measure it in meters or furlongs, but that doesn't mean that we can mix the two in computations.  The same is true here: instead of multiplying a real quantity by the meters-per-furlong conversion factor, we could multiply a complex quantity by a phase change, and just like in the real case, the physical meaning would still be the same.  But we have to apply the same phase change to other quantities if we want them to be compatible and not mix "complex units".

Comment: the problem with this argument as stated is this doesn't single out the global phase but could also be applied to the relative phase.

Answer (score -1):

The global phase does not matter because of charge-current conservation. According to the Noether theorem, charge-current conservation is related to invariance under a global phase change. As long as the problem at hand obeys charge-current conservation only phase differences have physical consequence.

Answer (score -1):

As the OP points out, many people say

> the phase of a wave function doesn't have physical meaning

and there are also some who say

> the state space of a physical system shouldn't be a Hilbert space, but rather a projective Hilbert space

But an alternative view that the OP might find less confusing is

> The state of a physical system is a vector in a Hilbert space, but is a global U(1) symmetry that prevents us from observing the overall phase factor of the state of the universe. More generally, an observer confined to an isolated system cannot observe the overall phase factor for the system.

One might object that this statement fails to convey some of the information that the previous statement is trying to convey: namely, the fact that any observable properties of a subsystem don't depend on the subsystem's phase. However, this fact just becomes a "theorem" as opposed to a "postulate". It follows from the fact that the phase factor of $|\psi\rangle$ cancels out when we evaluate $\langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$ for any Hermitian operator $A$. Whenever the phase of $|\psi\rangle$ *can* be observed, it is only through evaluating something like $\langle \psi' | A | \psi \rangle$ where $|\psi'\rangle$ is some other prepared state that $\psi$ can interact with; this is not an observable of $\psi$ alone.

---

Another person who answered this question mentioned Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields*. Because Weinberg does discuss projective space and rays for a particular reason, I want to address this in case the reader is not convinced that we can do away with the concept.

In Chapter 2 of the text, Weinberg discusses (among other things) the Poincaré transformation and mentions projective representations of the Lorentz group. It's thanks to the existence of these projective representations that we have half-integer spin. But one can use the theory of projective representations without using the projective *space* formalism as the ontology of quantum mechanics.

There are specific reasons why I think that we shouldn't say states are rays (elements of projective space). I think it's an attempt to make the unobservable phase factor disappear entirely from the ontology (sort of like how you often must do calculations on vectors using their components, but the vector itself has a coordinate-independent existence). However, one can do this only for an isolated system. As soon as we start examining subsystems that can interact with each other, we see that the state of the combined system contains more information than the states of the subsystems, since there are also $N-1$ phase factors if there are $N$ subsystems. I believe that because this violates some people's intuition about what the word "state" is supposed to mean, it leads to confusion.

None of what I'm saying alters the *substance* of Weinberg's text, though (far be it from me to challenge the actual physics). In particular, the reasoning still stands that each field should correspond to a *projective representation* of $SO^+(3, 1)$, which may fail to be an ordinary representation (in which case the spin is half-integer). Suppose we have $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2 \in SO^+(3, 1)$ (the proper orthochronous Lorentz group). We can still assign to each Lorentz transformation an operator that acts on physical states, and we must have, like (2.2.10) in Weinberg,

\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda_2) U(\Lambda_1) |\psi\rangle = e^{i\phi(\Lambda_2, \Lambda_1)} U(\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1) |\psi\rangle
\end{equation}

Weinberg's *interpretation* of this relation is that performing the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda_1$ then $\Lambda_2$ must yield the same *state* as performing the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1$, but since a *state* is a ray, that means there may be a phase factor when comparing the *vectors*.

The alternative interpretation I suggest using, which doesn't involve rays, is to say: doing $\Lambda_1$ then $\Lambda_2$ doesn't always yield the same state as doing $\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1$. However, the two states should yield the same values for all observables, therefore they can only differ by a phase factor.

Comment: Speaking of a global $\mathrm{U}(1)$ symmetry in this case is not accurate. Phase ambiguity is not a symmetry, but rather a redundancy in the description of the system. In a system with a global symmetry configurations related by a symmetry transformation are physically distinct. There exist physical observables which are not invariant under the symmetry. Measurement of these observables allows to distinguish states related by a symmetry transformation. If a group of transformations describes redundancies of the description, no such observables exist. This is the case of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Blazej I don't really get what yo're trying to say. Multiplying every state vector by some phase does leave the physics invariant in the same way as "rotating" (in fancy words acting on them by a $SO(3)$-action) leaves the physics invariant. You just view the system from a different perspective.

Comment: No, this is not the same. If you multiply a wavefunction by a phase, the new wavefunction represents exactly the same physical situation. On the other hand in the case of rotational symmetry of physical space it is not true that rotated system is the same physical system as the unrotated one, even though it happens to be true that looked upon in a different reference frame the new situation looks the same as the original situation viewed in the original reference frame.

Comment: @Blazej If the whole universe hypothetically had a different rotational orientation, we wouldn't be able to tell, since we're inside the universe. In that sense the analogy with the quantum mechanical phase holds. On the other hand, when a subsystem of the universe is either rotated or altered in phase, we can tell from outside the system.

Comment: If $\psi$ is a normalized vector representating some quantum state, $\psi' = R \psi$ where $R$ is the unitary operator representing some rotation in physical space and $\psi'' = e^{i \alpha} \psi$, then there exists an observable represented by an operator $\mathcal O$ such that the expectation values $(\psi, \mathcal O \psi)$ and $(\psi', \mathcal O \psi')$ are different. There is not such operator for $\psi$ and $\psi''$.

Comment: What you are claiming could be true in a hypothetical generally covariant quantum gravity theory, but for now we don't have such a theory (or at the very least we don't have one which is generally accepted as the one which describes the physical world).

Comment: @Blazej you are of course correct that a phase shift does not alter any observables of the system. Am I correct in understanding that you believe I am misusing the word "symmetry"? There are however plenty of sources that refer to the "global U(1) phase symmetry" or similar. So there are two ways in which the word is used: one broader and one narrower.

Comment: I agree that there are several different things people have in mind when talking about symmetries, but I think in discussion such as this one it is necessary to make a distinction, in order to clarify misconceptions some people have.

Comment: @Blazej I've already explained in my answer that the phase doesn't affect any observables. Since that seems to be the only difference between your definition and my definition, I am not sure why any hypothetical readers would be confused here.